# Code review: add columns to geopandas geodataframe based on sums of xarray dataset values, filtered by geoseries geometry

Tags: dask, spatial, geopandas, python-xarray

**Edit: Solved it**

Turns out I just needed to find [geocube](https://corteva.github.io/geocube/html/examples/zonal_statistics.html), a wonderful library for zonal statistics. That tutorial provides a great example for analysis on a `DataArray`; here's my code for analysis on multiple rasters in a `Dataset`.

Again, please point out any room for improvement! Thanks.

Alex

```
import geopandas as gpd
from rioxarray import open_rasterio
import xarray as xr

ssurgo_data = gpd.read_file("../../test/test_data/input/soil_data_group.geojson")
ssurgo_data = ssurgo_data.loc[ssurgo_data.hzdept_r==0]
ssurgo_data["mukey"] = ssurgo_data.mukey.astype(int)
tif_dict = {2000: 'path_to_2000.tif', 2001: 'path_to_2001.tif'}
xda_dict = {i: open_rasterio(tif_dict[i], mask_and_scale=True) for i in tif_dict.keys()}
elevation = xr.Dataset(data_vars=xda_dict)
elevation = elevation.rio.clip(
    ssurgo_data.geometry.values, ssurgo_data.crs, from_disk=True
).sel(band=1).drop("band")
elevation.name = "elevation"
out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=ssurgo_data,
    measurements=["mukey"],
    like=elevation, # ensure the data are on the same grid
)
for j in tif_dict.keys():
    out_grid[j] = (elevation[j].dims, elevation[j].values, elevation[j].attrs, elevation[j].encoding)
out_grid
```

**Original post**

The following code technically works, but it just seems very slow. I'm looking for ways to optimize it. Any suggestions welcome. Thank you!

I'm relatively new to `xarray` and I think I'm just missing something simple. I have an `xarray.Dataset` comprised of about 20-30 rasters. Each file represents data for the same place across different categories (years, rain, temperature, etc).

I also have a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` covering approximately the same time and place. All geometries are `shapely.Polygon` objects. I would like to add one column to the `GeoDataFrame` per underlying file in the dataset, based on the sum of the data covered by each `Polygon`.

Alex

```
import geopandas as gpd
from rioxarray import open_rasterio
import xarray as xr


rasters = {
     2000: open_rasterio('path_to_2000_data.tif'), 
     2001: open_rasterio('path_to_2001_data.tif')
# ... include data across other years, categories, etc.
}
xds = xr.Dataset(rasters)

gdf = gpd.read_parquet('path_to_geometry.geoparquet')

def helper_xr_pop(
        poly: Polygon,
        xds: xr.Dataset
) -> dict:
    try:
        # clip the dataset by the polygon
        out = xds.rio.clip([poly])
        # convert the sums to a dictionary ({2000: 10, 2001: 20})
        out = out.sum().out.to_dict()
    except:
        out = {}
    return out

XR_DATA = 'xr_data'
gdf[XR_DATA] = dask_gdf[GEO_COL].apply(lambda x: helper_xr_pop(x, xds), axis=1)
s = gdf[[GEO_COL]].apply(lambda x: helper_gpd_pop(*x, xds), axis=1)
pop_df = pd.json_normalize(s)
gdf = gdf.drop(columns=[XR_DATA])
out_gdf = pd.concat(objs=[gdf, pop_df], axis=1)
```

I've tried implementing this in `pandas`/`geopandas`, `dask`/`dask_geopandas`, and `polars`, and they've all taken far longer than expected. My instinct is that `xarray` has a method for this, and I just don't know it. I've scoured the docs the last few days and have learned quite a lot, just not the answer to my question.

Comment: I think you are actually calculating zonal statistics? Based on the [performance tests](https://github.com/geofileops/geobenchmark/blob/main/results_zonalstats/GeoBenchmark.png) I did on this matter the QGIS zonal stats algorithm is 10 times faster than the other options I tested. [Here](https://github.com/geofileops/geobenchmark/blob/main/benchmarks_zonalstats/benchmarks_pyqgis.py) and [here](https://github.com/theroggy/cropclassification/blob/master/cropclassification/util/zonal_stats_bulk/_zonal_stats_bulk_pyqgis.py) is some sample code how to use it.

Comment: Hi @Pieter, you're exactly right. Found [geocube](https://corteva.github.io/geocube/html/examples/zonal_statistics.html) and it did the trick. Any thoughts on the edit I made? It seems to work like a dream. Thanks again.